# Show/Hide mat-table columns using Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I currently have a function which removes columns from a mat-table. This works perfectly well, although when I go to add a column back into the table as the column index isn't held. Is there any way to retain the column order when re-adding columns? Or potentially even a better way to do this?!

Thanks

```
component.ts

  dataSource : DataSource;
  displayedColumns = [
    "COLUMN1",
    "COLUMN2",
  ];

  columnClick(colName: string) {
    const colIndex = this.displayedColumns.findIndex(col => col === colName);
    
    if (colIndex >= 0) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(colIndex, 1);
    } else {
      this.displayedColumns.push(colName);
    }
  }
```

```
component.html

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="columnClick('COLUMN1')">
    <mat-icon></mat-icon>
    <span>COLUMN1/span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="columnClick('COLUMN2')">
    <mat-icon></mat-icon>
    <span>COLUMN2</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>

<div class='table-container'>
    <mat-table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="results">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="COLUMN1">
        <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>COLUMN1</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
          <span>{{row.COLUMN1}}</span>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="COLUMN2">
        <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>COLUMN2</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >{{row.COLUMN2}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using `columnDefinitions` and `hide` property.

**TS:** code inside component.

```
 columnDefinitions = [
    { def: 'id', label: 'ID', hide: this.id.value},
    { def: 'description', label: 'Description', hide: false}
  ]

  getDisplayedColumns():string[] {
    return this.columnDefinitions.filter(cd=>!cd.hide).map(cd=>cd.def);
  }
```

**HTML:**
Add `<mat-row>` in your table

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-row>
```

**Note:** Full demo code is available in [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-hide-columns-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine that we have a table with two columns: ID and name.

**TS**: By default ID is hidden.

```
columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinition[] = [
{ def: 'id', show: false },
{ def: 'nome', show: true }
];
    
getDisplayedColumns(): string[] {
return this.columnDefinitions.filter((cd) => cd.show).map((cd) => cd.def);
}
```

**HTML**: Through checkbox we toggle the table columns.

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="customize">
  <span (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" *ngFor="let column of columnDefinitions; index as i">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="column.show"></mat-checkbox>
    {{ column.def | titlecase }}
    <br />
  </span>
</mat-menu>
```

And we need to call the function getDisplayedColumns():

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns(); sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns()" class="element-row"></mat-row>
```